# AngularJS inject service that requires $http before manual bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

Here's my service

```
(function(angular, module){

    module.provider('auth', ['$http', function($http){
        this.$get = function(){
            return {
                user: function(){
                    return {then: function(){}}
                }
            }
        }
    }]);

})(angular, angular.module('auth', []));
```

I'd want to check the user before the app bootstraps, so i'm doing:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var auth = angular.injector(['auth', 'ng']).get('auth');

    auth.user().then(function(response){
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

but the `$http` service isn't resolved, infact if i do remove the dependency from the auth service i get no errors. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you try this way

```
// create an injector
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);

$injector.invoke(function($http) {
  $http.get(url).then(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  });
});
```

Your way:

```
(function(angular, module){

    angular.module('authApp', []).provider('auth', function(){
        this.$get = ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                user: function(){
                    return 123;
                }
            }
        }]
    });

})(angular, angular.module('authApp', []));

var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'authApp']);

$injector.invoke(function(auth) {
  console.log(auth);
  auth.user().then(function(response){
     angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  });
});
```

Comment: because i want to wrap auth in a separate service.

Comment: OK I have edited my answer, hope it will help you more now ;]